# Remove file with python

Tags: python, glob

```
import os
import glob


for pkg_name in glob.glob('../../pkg*'):
    if os.path.isdir(pkg_name):
          os.remove(pkg_name + "/dev-tools/emk-test/ro_template.bin")
```

I want to remove ro_template.bin file. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: file didn't removed.

Comment: Maybe because `isdir()` will not be true for files?

Comment: Try to `print('true')` if condition evaluate to true and `print('false')` on `else` statement

Answer (score 0):

[Try this:](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_remove.asp)

```
import os
import glob
for pkg_name in glob.glob('../../pkg*'):
    if os.path.exists(pkg_name + "/dev-tools/emk-test/ro_template.bin"):
        os.remove(pkg_name + "/dev-tools/emk-test/ro_template.bin")
    else:
        print("File not found.")
```

Comment: @QAEngineer Are you using Windows? Does it print "File not found."?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import glob
import stat
for pkg_name in glob.glob(os.path.join("..", "..", "pkg*")):
    file = os.path.join(pkg_name, "dev-tools", "emk-test", "ro_template.bin")
    if os.path.exists(file):
        try:
            os.remove(file)
        except PermissionError:
            print("chmod on permission error")
            os.chmod(file, stat.S_IWRITE)
            os.remove(file)
        break
    else:
        print("File not found.")
```